# Iterate to find a Map entry at an index?

Tags: java

I have a LinkedHashMap. I want to get the Foo at index N. Is there a better way of doing this besides iterating until I find it?:

```
int target = N;
int index = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Foo> it : foos.entrySet()) {
    if (index == target) {
        return it.getValue();
    }
    index++;
}
```

I have to do get random elements from the map by an index about 50 times for some operation. The map will have about 20 items in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
List<Entry<String,Foo>> randAccess = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Foo>>(foos.entrySet());
```

Then for index N with O(1) access...

```
randAccess.get(N)
```

Comment: You have spent O(N) creating a copy of all keys in the map. If anything gets inserted to the map, your copy will not be updated. *It is only O(1) for successive queries after the initial copy*.

Answer (score 3):

@Mark's solution is spot on.  I'd just like to point out that the offsets (positions) of the entries in a map (of any kind) are not stable.  Each time an entry is added or removed, the offsets of the remaining entries *may* change.  For a HashMap or LinkedHashMap, you've no way of knowing which entry's offsets will change.

- For a regular HashMap, a single insertion can apparently "randomize" the entry offsets.
- For a LinkedHashMap, the order of the entries is stable, the actual entry offsets are not.

The instability of the offsets and the fact that finding entry at a given offset is expensive for all standard map implementations are the reasons why the `Map` interface does not provide a `get(int offset)` method.  It should also be a hint that it is not a good idea for an algorithm to need to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I think I might've had the same commentary, except the OP is using a LinkedHashMap which keeps a linked list of the entries corresponding to insertion order for iteration...thus the order of iteration is stable over time...no?

Answer (score 0):

A simplification of @Mark's solution...
You only need the values, so each time you change a value in the foos Map, also update an array.

```
Map<String, Foo> foos =;
Foo[] fooValues = {};

foos.put(foos.name(), foo);
fooValues = foos.values().toArray(new Foo[foos.size()]);

// later
Foo foo = fooValues[N];
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava library can help in this case:

```
public static <T> T com.google.common.collect.Iterables.get(Iterable<T> iterable, int position)
```

[see javadoc: Iterables.get](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#get%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29)

For your case the code can be like this:

```
Iterables.get(foos.values(), N);
```