# Retrieve Nested Hashmap data from yaml file

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml

i have following yaml Data

```
networkLayerConfig: 
    eventMap: !!map
      !!int 100 : 
        !!int 1 : IDLING
        !!int 2 : ACCEPTING
```

I use yamlbean to read this data to the following class

```
class NetworkLayerConfig {
    private HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> eventMap;
}
```

I trying to access every key and its associated value pair.

If i try to access these data when it is declared in java class itself like

```
myHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, String>>();
myHashMap.put(100, new HashMap<Integer, String>());
myHashMap.get(100).put(1, "IDLING");
myHashMap.get(100).put(2, "ACCEPTING");
```

using this following code

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> oneMap : myHashMap.get(100).entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(oneMap.getKey());
    System.out.println(oneMap.getValue());
}
```

since i have to read the value 100 from the yaml file only (i.e, during runtime) i don't know how to access every data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3895546/365188

Comment: What does that `100` represent? Do you only need that specific code? If so, why do you have a nested map? If not, couldn't you use a constant?

Comment: hashmap structure{parentKey:{childKey,childValue}} 100 represents the parent key i don't need the specific code but some clues to proceed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem to access every value in hashmap

```
Iterator<?> iterator = myparentHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry myEntry = (Entry) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(myEntry.getKey() + " : ");
            HashMap<Integer, String> childHashMaps = ((HashMap<Integer, String>) myEntry.getValue());
            System.out.println("{");
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> childHashMap : childHashMaps.entrySet()) {
                System.out.print(childHashMap.getKey() + " : ");
                System.out.println(childHashMap.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }
```