# Retrieve key of Map by index

Tags: java, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bi-directional Map in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699492/bi-directional-map-in-java)

How can I retrieve key of `Map` by index when keys are not numeric and unordered ?

For example :

```
Map<String, Integer> test = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
test.put("a", 1);
test.put("b", 2);
test.put("z", 3);
test.put("m", 4);
```

I want to get `z` if I have index 2 or `a` if I have index 0.

I know I can do dirty loop with increment to get it but is there another smart way to do it ?

Comment: A possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895525/iterate-to-find-a-map-entry-at-an-index

Comment: As the map is sorted you can not predict the value of key by the index value

Comment: You can't. You can `entrySet()` and iterate (O(n)) but without implementing/keeping a reverse map that's all you have.

Comment: +1 @BrianRoach.  The answer is you can't.  (Though if you used [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) `ImmutableMap`, you could do `map.keySet().asList().get(index)`.)

Comment: Is the index based on insertion order or value order?

Answer (score 1):

What makes this a bit confusing is whether you're referring to the index based on the order the item is added, or based on the natural ordering of the key (eg: alphabetical)

You can obtain the list of may keys using map.keySet() but there's no guarantee the key set will be in the order which you add it in

You can use TreeMap instead of HashMap if you want to keep your data in some kind of ordering (eg: alphabetical ordering). If you prefer other way of ordering you can implement your own comparator

Comment: yes sorry, I have made mistake, it is well TreeMap not HashMap. I have made an edit on my post. Nivas suggest me a link and there is a good way to do what I am looking for. I will use it unless someone provide me another better solution.