# Accessing map using index in java

Tags: java, hashmap

Why is there no `map.get(index)` in a Java `HashMap` ?

To access the first key's value in a `HashMap` I have to put the keys into a list then  `list.get(0)` and then pass that to `map.get(list.get(0))`; I feel this is clumsy. Why is this so?

What would be the *right* approach to access, say, the "first or second element" from a  `HashMap`?

(please do not suggest "convert `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap` and access it by `Iterating`).

Comment: A Hashmap is not a sorted data structure. You should never use it if you want to access items in a sorted way, since concepts like "first element" are alien to a Hashmap.

Comment: I'm curious... Why do you want to do this?

Comment: in my code logic, i will be adding key with the values and after that logic, i am passing map and need to get first element to check some functionality..right now i am doing it by using list as i explained in the post

Comment: There is no *right* approach to access the n-th element from a `HashMap`, because the concept of "index" is completely meaningless for a `HashMap`. The currently highest voted answer (and comment) explains this quite clearly. What you are asking for is impossible. If you want a map that you can navigate, use an implementation of [`NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html). In addition, what exactly do you mean by "first"? First element you put in to the map? First element in a sorted map?

Answer (score 4):

Asking for "the first elemet" of a `HashMap` does not make sense, because the order can (and will, in general) change as elements are added and removed.

This is explained in the documentation for [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> "... makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

You can test it with the following experiment:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class M {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   for (int i=1, p=1; i<100000; i++) {
      m.put(""+i, i);
      if (i == p) { 
         p <<= 1;  // keys are reordered at power-of-two multiples
         System.out.println("at " + p + ": first is now " 
            + m.keySet().iterator().next());
      }
   }
}
}
```

The output is (JDK 1.7):

```
at 2: first is now 1
at 4: first is now 2
at 8: first is now 3
at 16: first is now 3
at 32: first is now 15
at 64: first is now 19
at 128: first is now 35
at 256: first is now 35
at 512: first is now 35
at 1024: first is now 338
at 2048: first is now 338
at 4096: first is now 1411
at 8192: first is now 3280
at 16384: first is now 6873
at 32768: first is now 10997
at 65536: first is now 10997
at 131072: first is now 10997
```

If you require repeatable ordering (= iterating over elements will always give you their order of insertion), you can always use a `LinkedHashMap`. Beware that they require a bit more memory and are slightly slower than the standard variety.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is not ordered: index `i` in a HashMap does not mean anything.

You can only access it with a key.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html:

"This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

So there is no first or second element ...

Answer (score 0):

If the order of elements is important to you, you should not be using Hashmap. Hashmap is not an ordered data structure.

Answer (score 0):

A map(ping) by definition does not have an ordering, either on the keys or values, that's why.

If you have a look at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29), you will see that eg. the keys are returned as a `Set`, not a `List`.

I suppose you could define a special map, which retained eg. insertion order, but that would not conform to the contract in the Java version, which specifically states that it

> "...  makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

HashMap internally uses `Set`. `Order is not preserved`. SO you can not access it using index.

Comment: Internally uses `Set`? Since when?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your looking for this: [Iterate to find a Map entry at an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895525/iterate-to-find-a-map-entry-at-an-index) or something else

```
List<Entry<String,Foo>> randAccess = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Foo>>(foos.entrySet());
randAccess.get(N)
```

Comment: That requires making a copy of all keys in the map, which is somewhat expensive.

Comment: Also, the OP explicitly said that converting to list-of-keys was out.